# Customise moreNavigationController's tableview and similar user interface

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have overridden `moreNavigationController` tableview, but I want to use same row that is default as native `moreNavigationController`'s tableview datasource(tabbaritem icon, name and badge etc.). 
I have tried to fetch cell from existing datasource. Below is my code snippet:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
{
    if (viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController && tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate == nil)
    {
        if tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view is UITableView
        {
            let view:UITableView = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as! UITableView

            tblDataSource = view.dataSource

            view.delegate = self

            view.dataSource = self
        }
    }

    return true
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tblDataSource?.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

But, it shows me blank cell.

Comment: What do you mean by "moreNavigationControlle"?

Comment: moreNavigationController is 5th tab ViewController if UITabviewController contains more than five tabs. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/moreNavigationController

Comment: Your question could do with additional description of your problem.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the following method to properly display the cells for the "More" view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tblDataSource?.tableView!(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't understand.
If you want same rows as native, then why would you override UITableViewDataSource methods? Leave as it is. Override the necessary methods those you need.

Comment: I need return value of shouldSelectViewController is false for one tab. Thats why I have to override it.